# Backbone.js hover event not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to use Backbone.js for the first time and I'm having some trouble. I don't know if my problem is that I'm not understanding how backbone is supposed to work or if it's just a code problem.

I'm trying to create a dynamic menu, and I have no problem creating the main menu bar with it's items, but I can't get the hover event to trigger whenever I hover one of the menu items.

**Views**

```
var MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(items) {
        this.menu = items;
        //Main navigation bar
        this.el = $("#main-nav");
        this.trigger('start');
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var me = this;
        _.each(this.menu, function(mi) {
            mi.render(me.el);
        });
        return this;
    },
    handleHover: function(e) {
        console.debug(e);
    }
});

var MenuItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className:'menu-item',
    events: { //none of these work
        'hover a':'handleHover',
        'mouseover a':'handleHover',
        'mouseover':'handleHover',
        'click': 'handleHover',
        'click a': 'handleHover'
    },
    initialize: function(mi) {
        this.menuItem = mi;
        this.el = $("<li class=\"menu-item\"></li>")
    }, 
    render: function(parent) {
        this.el.append('<a href="' + this.menuItem.get("link") + '">' + this.menuItem.get("text") + '</a>');
        parent.append(this.el);
        return this;
    },

    handleHover: function(ev) {
        console.debug("Hovering! " + ev + this.menuItem.get("cid"));
        console.debug(ev);
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Model**

```
var MenuItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        parent: null,
        children: [],
        link: "",
        text: ""
    }   
});
```

**Startup code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menu = new MenuView([
        new MenuItemView( new MenuItem({link: "/", text: "Home"})),
        new MenuItemView( new MenuItem({link: "/", text: "Users"})),
        new MenuItemView( new MenuItem({link: "/", text: "Configuration"}))
    ]);
});
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

**Update**

Ok, after taking the definition of `el` outside of the `initialize` method on the MenuItemView view, it works, BUT that same element gets reused on all instances of the view, so I had to change the view to the following code in order to make it work the way I want it:

```
 var MenuItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: { //none of these work
        'hover a':'handleHover',
        'mouseover a':'handleHover',
        'mouseover':'handleHover',
        'click': 'handleHover',
        'click a': 'handleHover'
    },
    el: $('<li class="menu-item"></li>'),
    initialize: function(mi) {
        this.menuItem = mi;
        this.el = $(this.el).clone(true);
    }, 
    render: function(parent) {
        this.el.append('<a href="' + this.menuItem.get("link") + '">' + this.menuItem.get("text") + '</a>');
        parent.append(this.el);
        return this;
    },

    handleHover: function(ev) {
        console.debug("Hovering! " + ev + this.menuItem.get("cid"));
        console.debug(ev);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Wny do I have to clone the element on a new instance?

Comment: Why do you have to clone your `el`? Consider when `$('<li class="menu-item"></li>')` is evaluated and you'll have your answer.

Comment: if I create the element for `el` on the `initialize` method, then the events are not triggered, how can I solve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Re: "Why do I have to clone the element on a new instance?"**

The underlying problem is right here:

```
var MenuItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ...
    el: $('<li class="menu-item"></li>'),
```

The `$('<li class="menu-item"></li>')` call is executed when `MenuItemView` is being defined so you end up with only one `$('<li>')` being shared across all instances of `MenuItemView`.

If you create the `el` inside `initialize` or `render` then you'll have to bind the events by hand using [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents):

> By default, `delegateEvents` is called within the View's constructor for you [...]

So if you create `this.el` yourself then you'll have to call `this.delegateEvents()` yourself. For example:

```
var MenuItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ...
    render: function() {
        this.el = $('<li class="menu-item"><a>' + this.cid + '</a></li>');
        this.delegateEvents();
        return this;
    },
    //...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/RPqMh/2/

However, if you [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) your `this.el` with the `withDataAndEvents` flag on, then you should be fine:

```
var MenuItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('<li class="menu-item"></li>'),
    // ...
    initialize: function() {
        this.el = this.el.clone(true);
        this.el.append('<a>' + this.cid + '</a>');
    }, 
    //...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hCW3F/1/

But if you just `this.el.clone()`, it won't work because the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) won't be bound to the clone:

```
var MenuItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('<li class="menu-item"></li>'),
    // ...
    initialize: function() {
        this.el = this.el.clone();
        this.el.append('<a>' + this.cid + '</a>');
    }, 
    // ...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/KZNPA/

But if you add your own `delegateEvents` call, you'll be okay:

```
var MenuItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('<li class="menu-item"></li>'),
    // ...
    initialize: function() {
        this.el = this.el.clone();
        this.el.append('<a>' + this.cid + '</a>');
    },
    render: function() {
        this.delegateEvents();
        return this;
    },
    // ...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/KZNPA/1/

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! It cleared the whole thing up for me :)

Comment: @Deleteman: I had to make sure I had it all clear in my own head first so I shared my notes :)

Answer (score 10):

hover is not a normal event, but a 'convenience' event provided by jquery.  It is a combination of mouseenter and mouseleave.

Binding to mouseenter and mouseleave instead of hover will do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you don't need this properties:

```
tagName: 'li',
className:'menu-item'
```

in MenuItemView if you specify `this.el = $('<li class="menu-item"></li>')`;

Comment: Yes, that code was added during testing just to check if that'll solve my problem, but it didn't....

Comment: Yes, I also checked. Didn't fix. Anyway instead of `tagName` and `className` define directly `el: $('<li class="menu-item"></li>')` and it should work.

Comment: Yes, defining `el` outside of the `initialize` method works (kind of), but that same element gets reused on every instance of the view. I'll write an update to show you...

Comment: Hm, that's interesting.. I see the problem. For now I can only say that creating the instance like that `var menu = new MenuItemView({el: $("<li class='menu-item'></li>")});` seems to work as intended.

Comment: And btw, you would better use just `tagName: 'li', className: 'menu-item'`. it also works.

Comment: What does this.trigger('start'); do ?