# Why wont' backbone fire my event?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

My class is defined as below:

```
class NewUser extends Backbone.View
  template : JST["backbone/templates/events/new"]
  events : 
    'click button' : 'hello'
  hello : ->
    alert('hi')
  render : ->
    @el = $(@template())
    @
```

I initialize the page as follows:

```
$('body').append(new NewUser().render().el)
```

Yet when I click the button, no alert displays. Does anyone see anything wrong with my code? The view renders, but the events never register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating your `@el` in your `render` method:

```
render : ->
    @el = $(@template())
    @
```

but you neglect to call [`delegateEvents`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents):

> Uses jQuery's `delegate` function to provide declarative callbacks for DOM events within a view. [...] By default, `delegateEvents` is called within the View's constructor for you [...]

So, your events never get bound to the `@el` that you add to the DOM and your button does nothing useful. Your `render` should look like this:

```
render : ->
    @el = $(@template())
    @delegateEvents()
    @
```

Comment: delegateEvents gets called during the view's initialization, and since it uses jQuery's delegate method, there isn't a need to call it again.

Comment: @Paul: But he's replacing the `@el` after initialization so any existing delegates go away, play with this and you'll see: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SA6RB/

Comment: @Paul: I recently gave someone a lesson in this stuff (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8932216/479863) so it was pretty fresh in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Is the button part of the template which is rendered to the view's `el`?

If it's not then the `hello` event won't be fired because the events hash is limited to events within the view itself. You will need to manually bind to the event in the `render` method in that case

```
render : ->
  @el = $(@template());
  $('#buttonId').click(@hello);
```